# Is there any way to opacity only background of a text in css?

Tags: html, css, opacity

Is there a way to opacity only background-color of a text in css?(not text color...just background-color of The text)....I do not want use image background.

This is an example:

[enter link description here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wLmAC/)

background is opacity  but the text is opacity too...I do not want it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, use rgba():

```
div ul li a.title {
    padding: 0px 12px 0 0px;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,.2);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/wLmAC/3/)**

Answer (score 3):

Use `background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);`

**http://fiddle.jshell.net/wLmAC/1/**

Answer (score 2):

Use `rgba()` to get that transparent background you need, like this:

`background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);`